# Android -- Transferring Application to a Device

Tags: android, deployment, apk

I have just finished my android application and now it's time to test it under real-life conditions.  The only problem is I'm clueless as to how to take the application and transfer it over to a device.  I have already signed the application.  What's next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can connect the device to your computer you can do it by:

- Executing this on a command line: `adb install name_file.apk`, where `install name_file.apk` is inside the `bin` directory of the project. `adb` is a command line tool that lives in the `tools` directory of the SDK.
- Copying the .apk file directly to your device and opening with a file manager.

**If you are using Eclipse:**

*Windows:*

- Plug in your device
- Open the Android project
- Open the 'Run Configurations' Wizard. You can do it by clicking in the right side of the "Run" button (not in the button, but in the arrow next to it).

[image]

- Once you get there, click on the run configuration of your project. Then, on the 'Target' tab, choose *Manual*. It will let you choose manually the device where you want to run your program.
- Click `Apply` and `Run`
- From now on, and if your device is properly plugged-in, you will see the name of your device into a list of devices. If you select the item that corresponds to your device and click run, eclipse will automatically compile and install the program in your handset.

*Linux*

If you are using Linux, which would be weird since you seem to be afraid of the command line, you first have to create an `udev` rule by creating a file called `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules` and putting this content into it:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"
```

Where `0bb4` is the `idVendor` of your device. To know the idVendor you can use the `lsusb` command. Once you have done so, you can follow the steps I wrote in the Windows section.

Comment: Any idea why my device, although plugged in a working usb on my windows 7 pc, would not be visible in the list ? I have a Samsung Galaxy S phone.